# Python definition running more than once

Tags: python

I am trying to use the same definition a couple time in a script I am writting. I can get the def to work once but not the 2nd time, any help would be great.

```
def def_test(name):
     COUNT = 0
     Totals = {}
     for line in file_1:
         if COUNT == 0:
             COUNT +=1
             continue
         else:
              quantity = float(line[12])
              persons_name = line[14].strip(" ")
              if persons_name == name:
                     print(name)

if __name__ =="__main__":
     def_test("Adam")
     def_test("Bob")
```

How do I get this to look for "Bob" on the 2nd pass?

Comment: What is the definition of file_1?

Comment: What is the error? Also, shouldn't the function call be `test(...)`?

Comment: did you mean `test("Adam")`? If not, what is the definition of `name()`?

Comment: yes updated for corrections

Comment: You still haven't specified what is going wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since there isn't enough information in the question (at the time I write this...), my guess is that you're opening the file in some other place in your code, and `file_1` is a reference to that open file. When you iterate over it, you are reading to the end of the file. You will need to reset `file_1` to point back to the beginning of the file. Conceptually, the easiest way is to close it and reopen it.

Unless there's explicitly a reason to open the file in some other part of your code, the idiomatic way to iterate over the lines of the file is by using the `with` statement, which opens a file, runs your code, then automatically closes it again.

For example:

```
with open("the_file.txt", "r") as file_1:
    for line in file_1:
        ...
```

Opening files is a relatively inefficient thing to do, though for a simple program like yours the overhead is negligible. If you were opening this file hundreds of times a second or more, it makes sense to open it only once. In that case you would use a command called `seek` to move the internal pointer back to the start of the file. I suggest you get comfortable with using `with`, and only start to think about opening the file and using `seek` when you've determined you actually have a performance problem.

Comment: That did it. Is there a more effecient way that I should do it?

Comment: `file_1.seek(0)` will also do the trick without closing and reopening the file.

Comment: @kindall: Correct. However, since the OP apparently has no real concept of files I didn't want to confuse them.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
def def_test(name):
     COUNT = 0
     Totals = {}
     with open('file', 'r') as file_1: #open file each time you call function
         for line in file_1:
             if COUNT == 0:
                 COUNT +=1
                 continue
             else:
                 quantity = float(line[12])
                 persons_name = line[14].strip(" ")
                 if persons_name == name:
                     print(name)
```